# Deleting from firestore/storage does not flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

i'm have built an image gallery for users using Firebase Storage and React.
Upload and delete. My problem is deletion takes longer than it should.

Should happen:
Click on trashcan > confirm modal pops up > user clicks confirm > confirm disappears and delete process happens.

What happens:
Click on trashcan > confirm modal pops up > user clicks confirm > confirm disapears > user clicks on trashcan again > delete process happens and another confirm pops up.

```
export default function EditImageGallery({ handleUser }) {
  const imageListRef = useRef(ref(storage, `images/${handleUser}`));
  const [imageList, setImageList] = useState([]);

  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(true);
  const [continueDelete, setContinueDelete] = useState(false);

  //lists all images in a users repo
  useEffect(() => {
    listAll(imageListRef.current).then(async (response) => {
      const promises = response.items.map((item) => getDownloadURL(item));
      const urls = await Promise.all(promises);
      setImageList(urls);
    });
  }, []);

  //Delete process
  const onDelete = async (e) => {
    const { id } = e.target;
    console.log("onClick Url", id);

    setHidden(false);
    // set in the confirm modal
    if (continueDelete === true) {
      //delete in storage
      const deleteRef = ref(storage, id);
      console.log("continue with the process:", deleteRef);
      deleteObject(deleteRef)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Item was deleted from Firebase Storage", deleteRef);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
          toast.error(error.message);
        });

      //delete reference in firestore
      try {
        const imageDelete = collection(db, "images");
        const q = query(imageDelete, where("imageURL", "==", id));
        const snaps = await getDocs(q);
        snaps.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log("Deleted Doc: ", doc);
          console.log("Deleted Doc: ", doc.ref);
          deleteDoc(doc.ref);
          // window.location.reload(true);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    }
    setContinueDelete(false);
  };

  //show/hide confirm modal
  const toggleConfirm = () => {
    setHidden(!hidden);
  };

  //confirm deletion by modal
  const confirmDelete = () => {
    setContinueDelete(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {!hidden && (
        <ConfirmModal
          handleToggle={toggleConfirm}
          handleContinueDelete={confirmDelete}
        />
      )}
      <div className="w-full sm:w-4/5 container px-2 mx-auto pt-1 m-10">
        <div className="-m-1 flex flex-wrap md:-m-2">
          {imageList.map((url, index) => {
            // console.log(url, index);
            const imageURL = url.replace(
              `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com`,
              ``
            );
            return (
              <>
                <div
                  key={url}
                  className="relative flex w-full md:w-1/4 sm:w-1/2 flex-wrap"
                >
                  <div className="w-full p-1">
                    <img
                      src={`https://ik.imagekit.io/ajuaxvsrja/tr:q-50/${imageURL}`}
                      alt={`portfolio-${index + 1}`}
                    />
                    {/* Delete process starts here */}
                    <BsTrash
                      title="delete"
                      className="h-8 w-8 rounded-full bg-transparent absolute right-2 top-2 z-5 p-2 m-1 ring ring-red-600 text-red-600 text hover:ring-red-800 hover:text-red-800 cursor-pointer"
                      onClick={onDelete}
                      id={url}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Please let me know what in my code could be causing this.
I'm happy to add more code if you need to know something in particular.

Comment: I don’t think this is the reason of your problem but you should also use `Promise.all()` to delete the Firestore docs: `deleteDoc()` is asynchronous and returns a Promise.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I've added an ```async, await``` but the deleteDoc() still doesn't seem to resolve well, how do i do it with ```Promise.all()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. After the `setHidden(false)`, the `if` statement goes off and then once the state of `continueDelete` changes, the `if` statement is already evaluated and it doesn't get evaluated again.

I decided to use `useEffect` instead to evaluate and delete.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const deleteData = async () => {
      const deleteRef = ref(storage, id);
      console.log("continue with the process:", deleteRef);
      await deleteObject(deleteRef)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Item was deleted from Firebase Storage", deleteRef);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
          toast.error(error.message);
        });

      //delete reference in firestore
      try {
        const imageDelete = collection(db, "images");
        const q = query(imageDelete, where("imageURL", "==", id));
        const snaps = await getDocs(q);
        console.log("Number of documents to delete:", snaps.docs.length);
        snaps.docs.forEach(async (doc) => {
          console.log("Deleted Doc: ", doc.ref.id);
          await deleteDoc(doc.ref);
          console.log("Deleted Doc: ", doc.ref.id);
        });
        // await Promise.all(deletePromises);
        console.log("All documents deleted");
        window.location.reload(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        setContinueDelete(false);
      }

      setContinueDelete(false);
    };

    if (continueDelete === true) {
      deleteData();
    }

    return () => {
      console.log("cleanup");
    };
  }, [continueDelete, id]);

  //Delete process
  const onDelete = async (e) => {
    const { id } = e.target;
    console.log("onClick Url", id);
    setId(id);
    setHidden(false);
  };
```